# get data from api and show in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

i want to get data from API and show that in RecyclerView, then after click on any items, go to another activity and show the result that a get from another api.

i share image from postman with you and i hope you could help me for this

i'm using android stdio and java and i prefer to use retrofit for call from api

thanks for your attention...

[Brands Api for MainActivity.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7iVD.png)

[Products Api for Second Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ1wo.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Retrofit for getting data from API.. you can checkout a tutorial like this - https://howtodoandroid.com/retrofit-android-example/